# Match a single occurrence of a string in a sentence using regEx

Tags: javascript, regex

If a sentence says

> "Hello Hello"

the test should return false, but if its something like

> "Hello Jhon"

it returns true.

I thought this is all i had to do `/(hello){1}/`

Comment: Why not check how many matches you get? It would be a lot easier than trying to write a complex regex that only allows one occurence.

Comment: Isn't a regexp actually case sensitive by default?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution that doesn't complicate the regex, but counts the number of matches in a given string:

```
function isValid(str) {
   return (str.match(/hello/gi) || []).length === 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This RegEx will match any repeated word:

```
(\b\w+\b).+\1
```

## Explanation:

From [Regexper.com[image: Regexper]](http://regexper.com/#(%5Cb%5Cw%2B%5Cb).%2B%5C1)

## Code

To check that a string doesn't contain a match:

```
!("testing testing 1 2 3...".match(/(\b\w+\b).+\1/)) #=> false
!("testing 1 2 3...".match(/(\b\w+\b).+\1/)) #=> true
```